# Cold Turkey alternative for Mac

Tags: osx, website-blocker

I use 'Cold Turkey' on Windows to block the distracting websites on workdays.
I looked around and found the app 'Self control', but the maximum range it supports is just 1 day.

Is there any other software available out there that lets me block the websites for at least 5 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can try [Persistence](http://www.persistence-app.com). I double checked and it supports up to 30 day blocking.

Persistence is very similar to "Cold Turkey" or Self Control, although it redirects the websites to motivational quotes, rather than simply block them. (I personally found this a bit strange, since I don't know if they're tracking or getting ad revenue.)

The other suggestion would be to submit a feature request to [Self Control here](https://github.com/SelfControlApp/selfcontrol/issues) or even simply modify the code - it's open source.